# How to update tableviewcell using asynchronous methods in Swift 2.0?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, kinvey

as the title says, I am trying to fetch data from Kinvey and load the data I get to the table view. However, since all the query methods are asynchronous, I can't get the data until the table view finish loading.

Is there any way to wait for the completion block to finish then proceed to the next line of code where I load the data to table view cells?

Here is the method from kinvey that I need to use to get the data, and the completionblock only gets called after everything else finishes

```
     store.queryWithQuery(
     query, 
     withCompletionBlock: {()-> }
     )
```

Comment: reload table in completion block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do This:

```
store.queryWithQuery(
         query, 
         withCompletionBlock: {(/*here should be as pramater dataReturned*/)-> in
//assign self.data = dataReturned
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload table, your code must look like:

```
store.queryWithQuery(query) {
    // table view of table controller, i.e.:
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

If you need reload just specific cells, there is example of reload for one:

```
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .None)
```

You can also add one of provided type of animation, see in UITableViewRowAnimation enum.